# recording the primary key by logging in php

Tags: php, mysql

My project is checking the attendance of the instructors.
I have 2 tables; `tbl_ins` and `daily_logs` - both have the same primary key: `ins_id`.

In my login UI in PHP , the user will only input his username and password. But the `daily_logs` table will record `ins_id`, `ins_uname` and etc.

What I want to know is how can the `daily_logs` table record the `ins_id` of the username that is entered?

I did reference ins_id

```sql
`ins_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES tbl_ins(ins_id)
```

php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO daily_logs (`ins_uname`,`log_datetime`)
VALUES ('{$username}', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

Am I doing it wrong?

the table structures

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_ins` (
  `ins_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ins_fname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `ins_lname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `ins_contact` int(11),
  `ins_uname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `ins_pwd` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `ins_dor` TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ins_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ins_fname` (`ins_fname`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ins_uname` (`ins_uname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `daily_logs` (
  `ins_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES tbl_ins(ins_id),
  `ins_uname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `log_rmlab` int(11),
  `log_datetime` TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `pc_num` int(11),
  UNIQUE KEY `ins_uname` (`ins_uname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: ins_id is the primary key so it cannot be repeated for an entry .. you should use like user_id fetch it while recording a daily log and insert it in that table

Comment: @Syed Qarib hmm i'm a starter so i'm in a blur.sorry. can you please give me an example code? thank you.

Comment: show us the table structure of both tables .. its mainly a db structure change rather than the changes in your code

Comment: @Syed Qarib the post has been edited :)